# Tomcat MIME type CSS

Tags: java, css, spring, tomcat

I'm trying to load a `CSS` document using `Spring` framework and my browser is not able to load this document resulting in an error explaining "Could not parse because non `CSS` `MIME` types are not allowed in strict mode." I have tried every combination of settings in my `web-XML` file. Want a work around. The file exists and has been put outside the `WEB-INF` directory.

Comment: are you using spring security? then share your configuration.

Comment: So you have tried the mime-mapping to Tomcat's web.xml?
<mime-mapping>
  <extension>css</extension>
  <mime-type>text/css</mime-type>
 </mime-mapping>